# What existing module installs software required for running tests (PHPUnit, etc.)?

Tags: 8, testing

Running tests in Drupal 8 requires certain software to run, of course. However, I was surprised to not find a module, up-to-date set of instructions, or other turnkey method of identifying and installing the required software. It seems reasonable to expect the ability to "flip a switch" and enable testing. Instead, I've had to learn from successive error messages what software was required. So, what existing module or other turnkey method already exists to install the software required for testing?

If you try to run tests after a base install of Drupal 8, you get this message: "run-tests.sh requires the PHPUnit testing framework. Please use 'composer install' to ensure that it is present." However, more appears to be required than merely requiring phpunit/phpunit. The minimum list of software required for running tests appears to be:

- phpunit/phpunit (version dependent on your PHP version)
- symfony/phpunit-bridge
- behat/mink-goutte-driver
- mikey179/vfsstream
- behat/mink-selenium2-driver

If it helps to know my installation, it is: Drupal 8.8.4, PHP 7.2, PHPUnit 6.5.14, and Drush 9.7.2.

I've got to be missing something because this need seems obvious. Is there an existing module (or other turnkey solution) to install the "PHPUnit testing framework" or minimum software to run unit, kernel, and browser tests?

Comment: Everything you need is in Drupal's composer.json under require-dev ...

Comment: You require drupal/core-dev to get the required packages.